# How to match substrings by recognizing first four letters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want that the code reacts to an input by looking at first at the whole word.

If the code can't find a matching substring it looks only at the first four letters and then matches it with a word, that has the same first four letters.

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
function FT() {
  var str = document.getElementById("ip").value;
  var res = str.split(" ");
  document.getElementById("splited").innerHTML = res;

  var arr = str.replace("bankcard", "finance");
  var str = document.getElementById("arranged").innerHTML = arr

  // This part should not exist
  var arr = str.replace("bankrupt", "finance");
  var str = document.getElementById("arranged").innerHTML = arr
  // The part above was added only to get the right result

  var arr = str.replace("cartwheel", "vehicle");
  var str = document.getElementById("arranged").innerHTML = arr

  // This part should not exist
  var arr = str.replace("carthorse", "vehicle");
  var str = document.getElementById("arranged").innerHTML = arr
  // The part above was added only to get the right result

  var arr = str.replace("bookmark", "books");
  var str = document.getElementById("arranged").innerHTML = arr

  // This part should not exist
  var arr = str.replace("bookshop", "books");
  var str = document.getElementById("arranged").innerHTML = arr
  // The part above was added only to get the right result

}
```

```html
<textarea id="ip">bankrupt carthorse bookshop </textarea>
<button onclick="FT()"> match </button>

<p id="splited"></p>
<p id="arranged"></p>
```

Result for the input: "bankrupt carthorse bookshop" should be: finance vehicle books

Because:

bankrupt has the same first 4 letters like bankcard - so it gets matched with finance

carthorse has the same first 4 letters like cartwheel - so it gets matched with vehicle

bookshop has the same first 4 letters like bookmark - so it gets matched with books

Comment: It's replacing numbers for `x`?

Comment: no thats just to show that it is matching with the same pair

Comment: I edited it, so that it is easier to understand

Comment: To answer the title question, you recognise the first four letters by `str.startsWith("ABCD")`. But I don't really get what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: "*it looks at the first four letters and then matches it with "1"*" - did you mean "and then replaces these four letters by "1""?

Comment: But is there a way to command to look for the first four letters, instead of writing the four letters A, B, C and D

Comment: @Bergi no it shouldn't replace the letters. But it should use them as help to find the right match

Comment: Then I don't understand how you arrive at "*Result for the input: "ABCD123 ABCD ABCD12" should be: 1 1 1*"

Comment: "*is there a way to command to look for the first four letters, instead of [hardcoded letters]*" - `str.slice(0, 4)` does that. It's not really clear though that you are looking for different letters, as all of your example consistently used "ABCD".

Comment: This is a siplified version of the problem

Comment: I don't know if you oversimplified the problem or something, but I have no idea what your end goal is.. Can you provide a few more examples of start string = replaced string?

Comment: ok I will add more examples

Comment: @BrianThompson I just edited it to explain it better

Comment: What is the connection to the numbers? All three of the new examples have the same pattern, so why do they get different numbers?

Comment: @BrianThompson I just replaced the random words with actual words. I hope it is easier to understand it now.

Comment: @SavePain That is much clearer, thanks. Unfortunately I don't have time right now to dig into an answer, but I feel that the updated question could get better help now.

Comment: @BrianThompson Ok, no problem, thanks

Comment: @Bergi I added 'str.slice(0, 4)' to the code, but it only selects the first 4 letters of the input, instead of every single word. How would you use it? btw. I just replaced the random words with actual words so that the problem is easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure whether the word "*bankcard*" itself is relevant though, you just want everything that begins with "bank", right? Or are you getting those long words (with their respective replacements, like "finance" for "bankcard") as input somehow? In what format?

Comment: "*instead of every single word*" - you can loop over the `var res = str.split(" ");` to handle every word on its own. Alternatively you could use regular expressions, but I'd recommend getting familiar with the basics first.

Comment: @Bergi I want everything that begins with the same 4 letters to be matched with the same category like the word that has those same first 4 letters. I want that the code actually recognizes the first four letters of 'bankcard'.

Comment: And that's what `someWord.startWith('bankcard'.slice(0, 4))` does. But if you are really looking for a generic solution, how does your data structure that maps words to categories look like?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks that is useful but in `someWord.startsWith('bankcard'.slice(0, 4))` the `.slice()` part does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions and for loops are extremely handy for something like this. Let me know if you have any questions on how this works!

```html
<script>
  var search_and_replace = {
    "finance":["bankcard","bankrupt"],
    "vehicle":["cartwheel","carthorse"]
  };


  
  function FT() {
    var str = document.getElementById("ip").value;
    var res = str.split(" ");
    document.getElementById("splited").innerHTML = res;
    
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      var check = res[i];
      var add_str = ""
      if(add_str != "") break;
        for(var key in search_and_replace){
          if(add_str != "") break;
          for(var s_string in search_and_replace[key]){
            if(add_str != "") break;
            if(s.search(s_string)){
              add_str = key;
            }
          }
        }
      result = result + add_str + " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("arranged").innerHTML = result;
  }
</script>


<textarea id="ip">ABCD123 ABCD1 ABCD12</textarea>
<button onclick="FT()"> match </button>

<p id="splited"></p>
<p id="arranged"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the goal is, that the code searches for the first four letters instead of already knowing the first 4 letters, I just replaced the random words with actual words so that it is easier to understand what I am asking.

Comment: Untested, but the idea is there.

Comment: I don't think this solves your problem, but it should give you new tools to help solve it yourself.